# Do we need to register Custom Tag?

Tags: html, css, custom-element

I have been reading [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) about HTML5 Custom Element.

It said I need to register the element's name before using it like:

```
var XFoo = document.registerElement('x-foo');
document.body.appendChild(new XFoo());
```

Then I can start using it normally:

```
<x-foo>...</x-foo>
```

But I just tried using it without registering in Chrome, Firefox, and IE11. All seems to render just fine, even CSS selector for `x-foo` also works.

I'm guessing that we no longer need to register since most browsers have supported it?

Thanks

Comment: We need to register those because the old browsers (like IE's old versions) don't support it. I may be wrong.

Comment: @salep But old browsers don't support [document.registerElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No.

As a good practice, always define things that are not official. Just because it works by all/most browsers does not make it correct. That would be similar to using a variable which is yet to be defined, and then the compiler automatically defining it. Sure, it works, but that does not make it right

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also from the code in my question, do we need to call the `document.body.appendChild()` or just `registerElement()` is enough?

Comment: body.appendChild is not correct.  Your goal is to register it, so just register it.  For certain IE versions, you need to do `document.createElement('x-foo')` or else CSS doesn't work.  Also you should explicitly set the display css property for custom elements, because some browsers make different assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**: In any situation where it seems you don't need to register a custom element, you probably shouldn't be using a custom element in the first place.

---

The purpose of [custom HTML elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-intro) is:

> provide a way for authors to build their own fully-featured DOM elements

Emphasis on "fully-featured". They are designed so you can bundle up a packet of behaviour (expressed in JS) into a reusable component.

They aren't designed to be nothing more than *a nice name to hang CSS from*. They (in the most basic sense) work as that (mostly because HTML attempts to be forward-compatible and fail quietly), but using them tends to discard many of the benefits that HTML has in the first place.

The [specification also says](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-upgrades-examples):

> Because element definition can occur at any time, a non-custom element could be created, and then later become a custom element after an appropriate definition is registered. We call this process "upgrading" the element, from a normal element into a custom element.

i.e. If you don't register the element then **it isn't a custom element**. (IIRC, it is an *unknown element*).

The [original CSS 1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#class-as-selector) warns:

> CSS gives so much power to the CLASS attribute, that in many cases it doesn't even matter what HTML element the class is set on -- you can make any element emulate almost any other. Relying on this power is not recommended, since it removes the level of structure that has a universal meaning (HTML elements). A structure based on CLASS is only useful within a restricted domain, where the meaning of a class has been mutually agreed upon.

Using unknown elements as nothing more than something to hang CSS from has the same problem. You're discarding the semantic features of HTML and creating something purely visual.

There's no additional meaning that can be utilised by screen readers (you may be under a legal requirement to ensure your website is accessible, e.g. [in many contexts in the the UK](https://www.boia.org/blog/the-equality-act-of-2010-and-british-standards-for-web-accessibility)) and search engine indexing robots.

Answer (score -1):

No, and [`document.registerElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.registerElement) isn’t even supported widely. It is experimental technology, work in progress.

Browsers traditionally treat unknown element names as specifying elements that have generic properties of HTML elements but no default functionality and no default rendering (the content is rendered according to its own rules). However, old versions of IE ignore an unknown element name in CSS unless you introduce it with code like

```
<script>document.createElement('x-foo')</script>
```

Using `registerElement` is useless for such purposes, since it is not supported by IE.

If you use `registerElement`, you should take caution, since calling it causes an error and script termination in many browsers. So you would need code like

```
if('registerElement' in document) {
   var XFoo = document.registerElement('x-foo');
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will use `createElement` instead