# Are there technical reasons not to use undefined custom elements for everything?

Tags: html, custom-element

Some people seem to like to rewrite

```
<div id="homepage">[...]</div>
```

as

```
<app-homepage>[...]</app-homepage>
```

Are there any technical or spec related reasons not to do this? Mind that I am talking purely about changing this on the level of the HTML and CSS; The elements have not been defined using the custom elements API.

Comment: It depends. If you know the target browsers and you don't redistribute the code, no problem. otherwise no. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27853049/4600982

Answer (score 0):

Tl;dr: **Don't do it.** Use the custom element spec for what it's made for. Hacking together your HTML syntax is not what it's made for.

## Semantics

First of all custom elements in general can break up the semantics of the DOM structure. When custom elements are used properly you receive a lot of power in return, but in this way you give up semantics without any benefit. Instead use the proper HTML5 elements like `<header>`, `<article>`, etc.

## Undefined custom element state

According to the custom elements spec such elements have a custom element state of

> "undefined" (not defined, not custom)

Now, the way the HTML spec works any element which isn't recognized has a defined behavior of create just a default undefined HTML element instance.

Up till the custom element spec it was incredibly dangerous to define such elements because there was a risk that a future version of HTML would implement it, but now all elements with a `-` are reserved for custom elements.

Does that mean that you are entirely safe? No, because you put yourself in the same namespace as all other custom elements. And unlike with external stylesheets there is no proper way to namespace them, so if you wish to do something like this you will have to write code like

```
<my-app-name-homepage>[...]</my-app-name-homepage>
```

and even then you still end up with an element with an `undefined` state.